# Azure Functions Http trigger when recieving a pdf file then Analyze the form with Form Recognizer [python]

Tags: python-3.x, azure, function

So the following Workflow:

1. A colleague sends a delivery receipt (pdf or image) on my Azure Functions Endpoint.
2. The Azure Function uses the HTTP trigger to recieve the file.
3. The file then is going to be analyzed by the FOrm Recognizer (Cognitive Services of Microsoft)
4. Send a Response in form o a Json.

As I am new to this, I have some problems. This is how my code looks right now:

```
import logging 
import requests
import azure.functions as func
import json

SUPPORTED_CONTENT_TYPES = ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png']

# Define Form Recognizer Dependencies

apim_key = "key"
model_id = "formrecognizer model id"
formrecendpoint ="endpoint"

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Function processed a Request')

    # recieve the file
    file = req.files.get('file')

    body = None

    # Analyze Forms Endpoint  
    endpoint = '......cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/cutom/models/modelID/analyze'

    # Analyze Form
    response = requests.post(endpoint, data = file, headers = {"Content-Type": '<file type>',"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": apim_key})
    body = response.content

    #Return Response
    return func.HttpResponse(body,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
```

But it just doesn't work.

I get the following error when trying to post a file via Postman (form-data , binary)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "1002",
        "message": "Analyze request is either invalid or missing required parameters. Refer to the API reference and retry your request."
    }
}
```

But in the Function itself I get `STATUS: 200`.

Comment: Is this the actual URL, or do you have a `modelID` in place? The error says the "Analyze request is either invalid or missing required parameters" so have a look at the [documentation](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm). The reason the Function returns a `STATUS 200` is because you're always returning a `func.HttpResponse`.

Comment: https://region.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrec/v2.0-preview/custom/models/ec7....be3fc...../analyze

The URL shouldnt be the problem. I double checked it a few times. I have a custom model ID in place. 
I am fairly sure that I dont pass the body right, and the parameters.